# Problema com cursor em MySQL

Tags: mysql, cursor

Boa tarde!

Estou criando com sucesso o seguinte cursor:

```
declare v_cursor cursor for
    select idCliente, max(dataVenda) from Cliente
    left join Venda on idCliente = cliente_idCliente
    group by idCliente;
```

Porém ao executar o comando `fetch` recebo o seguinte erro:

> Error code 1329, SQL state 02000: No data - zero rows fetched,
>   selected, or processed

Aparentemente ele acusa que o `select` não retornou nenhuma tupla ao cursor. **Porém, quando eu executo o `select` isolado, ele retorna dados**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe me dizer por que isso acontece?

Existe uma forma de contornar esse problema?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou a declaração do HANDLER:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690018/194717

Comment: Realmente, eu havia esquecido de declarar o handler! vlw